# code not getting uploaded to Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

when I try to upload any code to Arduino it isn't getting uploaded the "RX LED" keeps blinking about 10 times but the "TX LED" doesn't light up. I have done a loopback test but it failed the cable is working there is no problem with my cable "Pin 13 LED" and "ON LED" are working, also my Arduino is not getting recognized in the device manager, my Arduino was working before. My Arduino model is: "UNO R3".
the error I get when I upload the code:

```
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x49
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

Comment: i dont have another Arduino to burn bootloder